# Can I impose order in the rules of a Makefile?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm using a `Makefile` to build several complex tests, all with the same structure but on different folders.

Each test has a long of files to build and my top level rule says

```
.PHONY : all
all: $(TESTS)/my_program
```

This works, but it will intercalate the build of all tests. So it would do something like

```
mkdir -p test1/build
mkdir -p test2/build
mkdir -p test3/build
clang -c test1/my_test.c 
clang -c test2/my_test.c 
clang -c test3/my_test.c 
...
```

That result does not make it easy to read when a test fails. Is there a way to impose order on the rules such that it builds one test at a time? Say something like

```
mkdir -p test1/build
clang -c test1/my_test.c 
...
mkdir -p test2/build
clang -c test2/my_test.c 
...
mkdir -p test3/build
clang -c test3/my_test.c 
...
```

Comment: You've not shown how your makefile actually works, so there's not much we can say.  Presumably `$(TEST)/my_program` depends on some things, and those things either depend on or invoke commands like `mkdir` and `clang`, but since you don't show how any of that we can't help.  In any event, `make` only runs one command at a time by default so I don't understand the question.  If we saw the makefile maybe it would make more sense.